# How can I craft a regular expression to match a comma delimited list with a maximum of 5 items in the list?

Tags: javascript, regex

Examples that should match the regex:

- green, yellow-3, 12345, hello, world
- blue, red, teal, orange
- green,12345, world
- hello, there
- green

I want to create a regular expression that matches a comma-delimited list with these rules:

- The list can contain 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 items.
- The items must not contain white space except for an optional space after each comma.
- The last item must not have a trailing comma.
- Each item must be between 2 and 30 characters.

What I have so far (doesn't work):

```
/^([a-z0-9]{2,30}, ?)?[a-z0-9]{2, 30}$/i
```

Comment: I think the enhancement being suggested is to add the {0,4}

Comment: what's the spec for individual items? any non-comma character? a-z0-9 and hyphen?

Comment: `a-z0-9_-` should be all I need for now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out this:

```
/^[a-z0-9-]{2,30}(,\s?[a-z0-9-]{2,30}){0,4}$/i
```

**Break up:**

```
/^
   [a-z0-9-]{2,30}   # One item for sure
   (                 # A capture group. You can make it non-capture if not required
      ,\s?              # Comma followed by optional space
      [a-z0-9-]{2,30}   # Another item
   ){0,4}            # 0 to 4 repetition.
$/ix
```

You can even shorten your regex by using `\w`, which is equivalent to - `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, after your updated comment, where you said you can accept `_` also. So, just use this:

```
/^[\w-]{2,30}(, ?[\w-]{2,30}){0,4}$/
```

Comment: Don't match `yellow-3` though. ;-)

Comment: Also doesn't match `green,12345, world` ;-) (probably want `^[a-z0-9-]{2,30}(, ?[a-z0-9-]{2,30}){0,4}$`)

Comment: And now you get +1 from me. ;-)

Comment: it also matches --,- which I doubt the op intended, but they haven't specified exactly what the items should be like

Comment: @BradChristie In [my link](http://refiddle.com/gvw) I fixed that already. It works :)

Comment: @BobbyJack those matches are okay.

Comment: @AlexFord: Comment links an answer do not make. But your answer is corrected now and I've officially up-voted it. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie I didn't intend my comment to be an answer, just a working example of this answer, which happened to have the fix for the optional space.

Comment: @BradChristie Alex is OP. He's just showing it works now, in an external link ;)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
/^([a-z0-9-]{2,30}, ?){0,4}[a-z0-9-]{2,30}$/i
```

This will match a 2 to 30 Latin letters or decimal digits or hyphens, followed by a comma and an optional space, all repeated 0 to 4 times, followed by 2 to 30 Latin letters or decimal digits or hyphens.

You can test it out [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9-%5D%7B2%2C30%7D%2C%20%3F%29%7B0%2C4%7D%5Ba-z0-9-%5D%7B2%2C30%7D%24&input=green%2C%20yellow-3%2C%2012345%2C%20hello%2C%20world%0Ablue%2C%20red%2C%20teal%2C%20orange%0Agreen%2C12345%2C%20world%0Ahello%2C%20there%0Agreen%0A%0Atoo%2C%20many%2C%20items%2C%20in%2C%20this%2C%20list%0Ainvalid-ch%40racters%0Acontains%20spaces%0Aends%2C%20with%2C%20comma%2C).

Comment: Is that not exactly what I used in my question that didn't work?

Comment: @AlexFord No it isn't. you had a `?` after the first group. I replaced it with a `{0,4}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[^,]{2,30}(, ?[^,]{2,30}){0,4}$/
```

The `[^,]` are used because you didn't specify allowed characters so I assume that only comma is not allowed.  You could of course use `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`, `\w`, or any other restrictions on that character class.

Comment: Except that `[^,]` allows spaces in the elements of the list!

Comment: @Jerry excellent point; should probably be `[^, ]` but I think there are more restrictions; `[\w-]` is probably what is desired